# Nginx High Open TCP connections

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, tcp

My web page got error 500 and dropped. Checking my Nginx's metrics in GCP, I detected:

- To many Open TCP Conecctions.
  [Open TCP Conecctions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYY2E.png)
- To many Accepted and Handled Conecctions
  [Accepted and Handled Conecctions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5WIU.png)
- To many Writting Connections
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fymjp.png)
- Normal Request per minute for each different IPs from Access.log (in compare with others days and months)
  [Nginx's requests from acces.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kiDc.png)

=> The drop in the graphs is because I restarted the server.

So, according to these metrics, I don´t see any relation beetween the amount of connections (TCP, Accepted, Handled and Writting) and the requests (acces.log).
Further, Is normal these amount of Open TCP connections? I don't think.

I'll appreciate your opinions and possibles reasons why happened this.

Answer (score 0):

500 is a server side error generally occurs if server is unable to process request. The webserver throws [500 internal server error](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) when it encounterd an unexpected condition which prevents it from fulfilling the client's request.

The [probable cause](https://www.ionos.ca/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/http-error-500-internal-server-error/) of 500 error could be because of:
Permission error.
Incorrect code in .htaccess file
PHP timeout.
Syntax or coder erro in CGI/Perl scripts
PHP memory limit